# how to find glcm of an image in OpenCV or numpy?

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, image-processing, glcm

I have to find texture based features of an image like correlation, energy, homogeneity, and contrast in Python. I am using python-opencv to do other operations, since python-opencv returns image as an numpy array. But I didn't find any good resource to compute GLCM using either opencv or numpy. Also I have to extract feature for `d=1` and `angle=[0,45,135,90]` and then use this feature in svm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to install the following libraries `scipy`, `numpy` and `skimage`.

`skimage` has a module called `skimage.feature` which includes
`skimage.feature.greycomatrix` and `skimage.feature.greycoprops`. Using these we can calculate the `greycoimage` for `ndarray` `uint8` and also the greco proporties [instructions](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/api.html)